# JSON errors after adding in Async in android application

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am having a few issues in two classes of my application I have addatched weblinks so you can see screen shots of my issues as well as the code,

loginActivity - https://i.stack.imgur.com/syP8T.png
JsonParser - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZobCF.png

```
LoginActivity code
class LoggingTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...nothing) {
            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunctions.loginUser(KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD);          
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (!KEY_USERNAME.equals("") && !KEY_PASSWORD.equals("")) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect   USername or Password");

                    //String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) ==1){
                     DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler (getApplicationContext());
                     JSONObject json_user = json.getObject("user");

                  // Launch Dashboard Screen
                     Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                  // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                     dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                     startActivity(dashboard);
                     finish();


                }else{
                    //Error in Login
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();



}
  }
```

JSONParson code

```
public class JSONParser extends Activity {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LoginTask task = new LoginTask();
            task.execute();

            }

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFormUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {  

     private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, String> {
        public List<NameValuePair> params;
        public String url;
```

Comment: In the future, please post the error message.  But your problem with the login task is that you need to define it at class scope, not inside of a method.  Your other problem is scoping related as well-  json is defined at method scope, and would need to be class scope or returned.

Comment: Hello Gabe, thank you for replying to my question, in regards to the login task could you please expand?